# Java/Android, is it possible to get contents of an Object?

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick

As the title suggests. I've done a bit of research and tried Jackson which seems like it should have worked but I had ridiculous amount of errors while trying to use it so that seemed a no go.

Basically my problem is this, I have my list view populated by an adapator as so:

```
friendsArrayAdapter = new FriendsArrayAdapter(
        NetPlay.this, R.layout.rowlayout,      friends);
listView.setAdapter(friendsArrayAdapter);
friendsArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and Then I want to handle onClick events within this listview, to copy the contents of that list view to a variable:

```
listView.setClickable(true);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, 
                int position, long arg3) {

           Object o = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
           Object o = arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);

         //mText.setText(o);
        }
 });
```

Now this all works fine, but the value returned is the actual Object ID/Reference 
Shows as something@Friends.21312. What I want is the actual contents which should be a Name + ID.

Is this even possible or do I need to redo my whole list view population?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

       //friends is the array that is given to the Adapter.
       //given friends = Friend[]
       Friend f = friends[position];
       f.getName();
       f.getID();
}
```

This is only a guess, please post your whole code for better help!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,  the  Friend f = friends[position]; part makes loads of sense, I just need to figure out how to get the names now. - My new issue is that this code:
 String newname;
               Friend f = friends.get(position);
               newname = Friend.name;
               
               //Object o = arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
               mText.setText(newname);
Works but wants name to be a static, however if I make it a static my entire listview contains the same name and ID, confusing

Comment: you reference static in your code, try f.name instead of Friend.name :)

Comment: @RaidenXL You can get this way either `Friend f = (Friend) friendsArrayAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position);`, need to be casted explicitly.